# How to prove this inequality for spectral norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How to prove for linearly independent eigenvectors $x_i$ whit $\|x_i\|_2=1$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ with corresponding eigenvalues $|\lambda|_1>|\lambda_2|\geq\dots\geq |\lambda_n|$ that this inequality holds for every $k\geq 1$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \|\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^k x_i \|_2^2&=& \left<\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^k x_i ,\sum_{j=2}^n \frac{\alpha_j}{\alpha_1}\left(\frac{\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}\right)^k x_j\right>\\
    &\leq&\sum_{i=2}^n\left(\frac{\alpha_i}{\alpha_1}\right)^2\left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_1}\right)^{2k}
\end{eqnarray*}

This is an estimation of the error of Power Method.
[image]

Comment: This certainly isn't true in general. What is the matrix in question? What are the $\alpha_i$s?

Comment: I will Edit my question with an image of the book "Numerical Mathematics" where I found the proof.